# Criar rotas para um unico ponto API google Maps

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-maps, ionic

Estou com um problema, o problema é o seguinte, fiz uma requisição via HTTP peguei os dados do JSON e carreguei dentro de um for assim consegui carregar todos os pontos do JSON para dentro do mapa:

```
var get = function(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                callback(xhr.responseText, xhr.status);
            }
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send(null);
    };


    get("http://site/", function(data, status){
        var dH = JSON.parse(data);
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < dH.length; i++) {
        var dHs = dH[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: parseFloat(dHs.latitude), lng: parseFloat(dHs.longitude)},
                map: map,
                icon: "img/"+dHs.icon,
                title: dHs.nome_hs,
            });
    }
```

Tentei dentro do for criar uma rota , mas obviamente nao deu certo pois a rota foi criada para a ultima localização carregada dentro do for, agora preciso achar um jeito de criar uma rota até uma localização especifica que está dentro do arquivo JSON onde fiz a requisição e tudo mais, enfim, é basicamanete isso, caso nao entendam, só perguntar! Obg!

Comment: Já resolveu o problema? Como está criando a rota? Pelo que vi no código apenas está colocando os markers no map

Comment: Já resolvi sim, puxei o  merker como parametro pra uma function e logo depois implementei a rota, assim ele pega somente o valor do marker clicado.